# django-rest-framework. Удаление записи из БД по нескольким условиям

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

У меня есть следующая модель данных:

```
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CourseParticipant(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='courses', on_delete=None)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='students', on_delete=None)
    completed = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course
```

Есть сериализатор:

```
class AssignStudentToCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = CourseParticipant
    fields = ('id', 'student', 'course')

class UnassignedStudentFromCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = CourseParticipant
    fields = ('student_id', 'course_id')
```

И вьюхи

```
class AssignStudentToCourse(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AssignStudentToCourseSerializer


class UnassignedStudentFromCourse(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = UnassignedStudentFromCourseSerializer
    queryset = CourseParticipant.objects.all()
```

Есть таблица в бд, которая соответствует модели CourseParticipant

`| id         | course_id   | student_id   |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      2      |     2        |
| 2          |      3      |     2        |
| 3          |      2      |     3        |
| 4          |      2      |     4        |`

Мне нужно удалять записи из таблицы  по полям course_id и student_id. Сейчас, используя во вьюхе DestroyAPIView я могу удалять записи только по id. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу реализовать удаление по полям course_id и student_id. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это для удаления

```
CourseParticipant.objects.filter(student_id=student_id, course_id=course_id).delete()
```

Но из моделей видно что CourseParticipant на самом деле кастомная реализация связи многие ко многим. Если нужны дополнительные поля в связях то это стандартная промежуточная таблица почитать можно тут:
https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/db/models.html#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships